# Isolating for i

Tags: calculus, finance, actuarial-science

So this might seem a bit fundamental, but in financial math the following equation gives you the price for a bond

$$
P = C \frac {1-(1+i)^{-n}} {i} + B(1+i)^{-n}
$$
where  $P$ is the price of the bond, $C$ is the coupon bond (the payment you get for buying the bond), $B$ is the Bond's value, and $i$ is the interest rate.
So naturally $ P,C,B \in \mathbb R $ and $ i \in (0,1) $.

Now my question is, how would one solve for the variable $i$ ?
This should an algebraic question, which is why I am putting it here.

What I tried so far, is to do what is common to questions like this and sub $v = (1+i)^{-1} $.

and get $$ P = C \frac {1-v^n}{i} + Bv^n $$
and then reduce it to 
$$P-C = \frac{ v^n (C- iB) } {i} $$

I feel like there is a way to solve this through taylor expansion for $(1+i)^n$, but I have no clue D:

Again I need the equation to be rearranged for $i$.

Comment: It cannot be done in closed form when $n\ge 4$.

Comment: True, I did not catch that Substitution. I looked at the equation after he "reduced it to" Essentially I gave the tips for solving the $(1+i)^n$ situation. In other words, even though it seems fundamental, as the OP states, nothing is fundamental :)

Comment: It does make for a nice application of numerical root finding.  The "correct" root (from a financial point of view) can be quickly isolated, and then standard approximations (secant method, Newton's method) can provide as much accuracy as desired.

Comment: @imranfat that won't work, you will still have $v^n$ on one side. recall $v^n$ is just a convenient substitution I made for $(1+i)^{-1} = v$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas there should be a way, computers somehow manage to do this, I don't imagine they just keep guessing. There should be a way to at least approximate this.

Comment: @hardmath so I assume that computers just reinterate newton's or the secant method until they find something resembling the correct value ?

Comment: There certainly are numerical methods, specially designed for this kind of problem. General purpose numerical rootfinders will also work. My comment was specific to your earlier request for an "algebraic" method.

Comment: oh okay, thanks :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting $X=1+i$, you get 
$$
P X^n= C \frac {X^n-1} {X-1} + B \tag1
$$ giving an algebraic equation of the form
$$
P X^{n+1}-(P+C) X^{n}- B X+B+C= 0 \tag2
$$ then use **numerical algorithm** (using for example [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)) **to find the apropriate root** (in many cases:$0<X<2$) since when $n$ is great, you don't have a general finite formula (with radicals) for the solution.

Comment: neat, I guess this is as good as one can get it to be :o

Comment: In the above formulation an "artifact" root at $X=1$ (or $i=0$) has been introduced in (2) by the process of clearing the denominator in (1).  Better would be to carry out the division of $X^n - 1$ by $X - 1$, giving an $n-1$th degree polynomial on the right hand side of (1).

Comment: @hardmath You are right.